# How do I adjust the form of the inequality?

Tags: equation-solving, pattern-matching, polynomials, inequalities

I have some inequality ,like this

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x+y+z \geqslant 1 \\
2 x+6 y+3 z \geqslant 6 \\
a x+b y+c z \geqslant d
\end{array}\right.
$$
I want to put all the y's in this inequality on the left-hand side,like this
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y \geqslant 1-x-z \\
6 y \geqslant 6-2 x-3 z \\
b y \geqslant d-a x-c z
\end{array}\right.
$$

```mathematica
ieq =
 {
  {x + y + z >= 1},
  {2 x + 6 y + 3 z >= 6},
  {a x + b y + c z >= d}
  }
```

I can adjust it manually, of course, but it takes a lot of time, because I have a lot of these similar inequalities, so what do I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{barray, marray}=CoefficientArrays[Equal@@@Flatten@ieq,y];
marray.{y}>=-barray//Thread
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ruley = GreaterEqual[a_. x + b_. y + c_. z, d_] :> 
  GreaterEqual[b y, d - a x - c z];

ieq /. ruley
```

$$\{y\geq -x-z+1,6 y\geq -2 x-3 z+6,b y\geq -a x-c z+d\}$$

Answer (score 4):

I First tried Reduce, but Reduce gives additional conditions, which you probably do not want:

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]
ieq = {{x + y + z >= 1}, {2 x + 6 y + 3 z >= 6}, {a x + b y + c z >= d}}
Map[Reduce[#, y, Reals] &, ieq]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So one alternative is to cheat a little. Temporarily change `>=` to `==` and use  `Solve` for `anything*y` then replace `==` back to `>=`. The only problem is to make sure to solve for `anything*y` and  not just `y`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ieq = {{x + y + z >= 1}, {2 x + 6 y + 3 z >= 6}, {a x + b y + c z >= d}}
Map[Equal @@ # &, Flatten[ieq]];
Map[(First[#] - Last[#]) &, %];
Map[Solve[ (# /. ((Coefficient[#, y]*y) -> Z)) == 0, Z] /. Z -> (Coefficient[#, y]*y) &, %]
% /. Rule -> GreaterEqual
Flatten[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ok, not a short solution as one given by xzczd, but at least gives the correct answer now. My first one had logic error.

Comment: Well, but we don't know if `b>0`.

Comment: @xzczd Good point. Let me see if I can fix this cheating method. I will delete this answer for now.